# Strange looping behaviour in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is extremely basic, I am sure, but I am puzzled.

If I run call the following function in a browser:

```
function bar(){
    var userInput=prompt("Enter a number between 1 and 20");
    if(userInput>=1 && userInput<=20){          
        var x=Number(userInput)+15;
        for(var i=0;i<x;i++){
            console.log("<br> blah. x=" + x );               //line1
            //console.log("<br> blah. x=" + x + " i=" + i ); //line2            
        }
    } else {
        console.log("Invalid number; please try again");
    }
}
```

and supply (say) the value 5, I unexpectedly get the following ***one*** line of output:

```
<br> blah. x=20
```

If however I supply the same value, but comment out line one and uncomment line two, I get the following (expected) output:

```
<br> blah. x=20 i=0
<br> blah. x=20 i=1
<br> blah. x=20 i=2
<br> blah. x=20 i=3
<br> blah. x=20 i=4
<br> blah. x=20 i=5
<br> blah. x=20 i=6
<br> blah. x=20 i=7
<br> blah. x=20 i=8
<br> blah. x=20 i=9
<br> blah. x=20 i=10
<br> blah. x=20 i=11
<br> blah. x=20 i=12
<br> blah. x=20 i=13
<br> blah. x=20 i=14
<br> blah. x=20 i=15
<br> blah. x=20 i=16
<br> blah. x=20 i=17
<br> blah. x=20 i=18
<br> blah. x=20 i=19
```

Why is this?  Obviously there is a reason. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check for any errors? Can you create a Stack Snippet and show the working behaviour or expected behaviour?

Comment: Or console showing the same line as (20) times?

Comment: It is working as expected the console log is just showing the same thing 20 times so it gets grouped.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understand right, the console will have shown you:

[image: preview]

That means, the same line is repeated 20 times. See the 20 number in front? It's easier to understand this way, so console would group all the similar or same responses and show the number on the left.

Comment: Ah! Thank you! I'm using Firefox for this, and the 20 is on the far right-hand side of the console window.  I thought I was going mad there for a while. There's always a reason. Thanks also to other replies.

Comment: @JL_SO Ah the console standards - Firebug vs. Firefox vs. Chrome. They are here just to confuse the stuff out of us, isn't it? `:D`

Answer (score 1):

You don't get one line, it's the behaviour of the developers tools of your browser to show one line if all the following are the same.

It looks like this:

> [image]

Notice "20" before the log.

Comment: Funny how successful wording can trigger really more upvotes than just being first as I was (see @Praveen's answer who posted 4 seconds later :)

Comment: Yep, you have mine. You were the first. Nice. `:D` I believe at first, you didn't add the picture. `:)`

Comment: Absolutely right, you were first to come up with a pic and actually "grouped" is a better word to describe that

Comment: Ah, I get that. "grouped". I was thinking a lot for that word. I thought about merged, combined, etc. but grouped won finally! `:D`

Comment: Hey, which browser are you using BTW? I haven't see a console like that. The left side symbol?

Comment: @PraveenKumar that's Safari :)

Comment: Ah... I was expecting some browser. `:)` You are using the other version of Internet Explorer - eh, Internet Explorer for Mac! `:P`

Comment: @Praveen noooope, Safari is a great browser... or maybe not as great since there're not so many questions on SO that address any problems with Safari, but there're pretty many ones which are about problems with IE xD

Comment: Ha ha... I am working as a Front End (and Full Stack) architect. Have seen worse with Safari, being a WebKit based browser. Thinking of which, it has the fever of IE. `:D`

Comment: @Praveen 

Answer (score 0):

X will always evaluate to 20 while i is being increased by 1 each time your loop runs

Comment: Uh... How does this answer the question?

Comment: well if it always evaluated to 20 giving the same result via each loop. You'll only see what the user is experiencing. When the user logs i the console will display each increment. My answer needed to be elaborated on. But you might have already guessed that ;)

Comment: Alright, it would be wise to add those details in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

our console has grouped similar outputs. Likely there is a 19 beside the output.